# Typescript - exporting instance of class results in multiple instances

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an npm package that I published that exports something similar to the following:

```
export class LogManager {
  // implementation here
}

export const logManager = new LogManager();
```

I have another Angular npm package (built using ng-packagr) that has a peer dependency on the npm package above and imports and uses logManager.

I also have the top level Angular application that also imports and uses logManager and has a dependency on log package I first mentioned.

With that out of the way my problem is that the Angular package and the Angular application both receive different instances of logManager.  What can I do to ensure they both receive the same object?

Thanks!

Comment: Create an instance and export that instance instead

Comment: That's what I'm doing? In my code sample I instantiate LogManager as logManager and export it.

Comment: I meant to say you should do `new LogManager()` by itself and store it in a variable, then export that one instance instead

Comment: Uh, well, the code should work as it's written in the question and it should export single instance of `logManager` to be used in all modules that import it. Either there is a bug in the module loader or bundler that you are using, or there is something else not mentioned in the question.